# The practical importance of Graph Isomorphism Problem

Tags: graph, computer-science, isomorphism, industrial

It is known that Graph Isomorphism is important in chemistry (studying molecule structures) and in chip design. Are there other applications of significant practical importance, and how much money is involved?

Is the industry interested in new efficient algorithms, or WL and DeepWalk are enough? Having a new efficient algorithm for testing graph isomorphism, is it worth patenting it?

Comment: This is not an appropriate channel to ask such questions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic